# how to get the same output by destructing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the same output as in the first code with the second code but with a slight variation. I want to de-structure the list "players" and then get the same output.

Here is the first code:

```
import random


lottery_numbers = set(random.sample(range(22), 6))

players = [
    {"name": "Rolf", "numbers": {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}},
    {"name": "Charlie", "numbers": {2, 7, 9, 22, 10, 5}},
    {"name": "Anna", "numbers": {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}},
    {"name": "Jen", "numbers": {19, 20, 12, 7, 3, 5}}
]

top_player = players[0]

for player in players:
    matched_numbers = len(player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers))
    if matched_numbers > len(
            top_player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)):

        top_player = player

print(top_player)
```

I want to de-structure the list "players" to "name" and "player" and then compare the variable "player" with the numbers that matched with lottery_numbers
Here is the second piece of code:

```
for name, player in players[1].items(): 
    matched_numbers = len(player.intersection(lottery_numbers))
    if matched_numbers > len(
        top_player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)):

        top_player = player
print(top_player)
```

Pycharm seems to hit me with a error like this:

```
in   matched_numbers = len(player.intersection(lottery_numbers))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

PS: I am pretty new with python and don't know much about what the error evens means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are doing is saying `players[1].items()`, this would return:

```py
{"name": "Charlie", "numbers": {2, 7, 9, 22, 10, 5}}
```

because that is the first index of the `players` list. If you want to get the list of names, you can just do something like this:

```py
for player in players:
```

this will go through all the players and the lottery numbers would just be `player["numbers"]`

So your final code would look like:

```py
for player in players:
    matched_numbers = len(player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers))
    if matched_numbers > len(
        top_player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)):
        top_player = player

print(top_player)
```

If you want to split this into 2 different variables, you can use this:

```py
names = []
numbers = []

for player in players:
    names.append(player["name"])
    numbers.append(player["numbers"])

finalList = zip(names, numbers)
```

then do:

```py
for name, player in finalList
```

Comment: Isn't there a way where we can separate the "players" variable into two variables in the for loop and get the same output?

Eg:

`
for name, number in players:
    and so on
`

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to make, to do with how the players list is organised, ie. it's not a dict but rather a list.

```
import random


lottery_numbers = set(random.sample(range(22), 6))

players = [
    {"name": "Rolf", "numbers": {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}},
    {"name": "Charlie", "numbers": {2, 7, 9, 22, 10, 5}},
    {"name": "Anna", "numbers": {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}},
    {"name": "Jen", "numbers": {19, 20, 12, 7, 3, 5}}
]

top_player = players[0]

for player in players:
    matched_numbers = len(player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers))
    if matched_numbers > len(
            top_player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)):

        top_player = player

print(top_player)  

for player in players:
    name = player["name"]
    numbers = player["numbers"]
    matched_numbers = len(numbers.intersection(lottery_numbers))
    if matched_numbers > len(
        top_player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)):

        top_player = player
print(top_player)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just what I wanted!